# How can i display table row depends on matching selected dropdow box values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have two multiple dropdownbox and one table and one search button. After i click the search button i want to hide/show the table row depends on selected dropdownbox values matching.How can i do it?anyone help.

JS:

```
    var array1 = [];
    var array2 = [];

    jQuery('#codexpl tr').each(function () {
    var $row = $(this);
    var $firstCell = $row.find('td:first');
    array1.push($firstCell.text());

    var $lastCell = $row.find('td:last');
    array2.push($lastCell.text());
    });

    var selectedBrandarr=[];
    var selectedStatusarr=[];
    $("#search").on('click', function () {

    /*search function*/

    $('.multiSel span').each(function (index) {  
    selectedBrandarr.push($(this).html().replace(/,/g, "")); 
    })

    $('.multiSel2 span').each(function (index) { 
    selectedStatusarr.push($(this).html().replace(/,/g, ""));
    })

    jQuery('#codexpl tr').each(function (index) {
    var $row = $(this);
    var $firstCell = $row.find('td:first'); 
    var $lastCell = $row.find('td:last');

    if($firstCell.text()==selectedBrandarr[index] && $lastCell.text() == selectedStatusarr[index] )
    {
    alert("yes");
$(this).css('display','block')
    }
    else{
 $(this).css('display','none')
    alert("not match");
    }

    });

    });

    $(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
    });

    function getSelectedValuedropdownbox2(id) {
    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
    }

    $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
    });


    $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {

    var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ",";

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.multiSel').append(html);
    $(".hida").hide();
    } else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".hida");
    $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

    }
    });

    /*-----------------------------*/

    $(".dropdown2 dt a").on('click', function () {
    $(".dropdown2 dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $(".dropdown2 dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
    $(".dropdown2 dd ul").hide();
    });

    function getSelectedValuedropdownbox2(id) {
    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
    }

    $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown2")) $(".dropdown2 dd ul").hide();
    });

    $('.mutliSelect2 input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {

    var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect2').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ",";

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.multiSel2').append(html);
    $(".hida2").hide();
    } else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".hida2");
    $('.dropdown2 dt a').append(ret);

    }
    });
```

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/3J2Ns/59/

Comment: Why is this question so poorly formatted? Add it to a snippet and tidy it. Also the HTML is not valid. Also the jsFiddle has duplicated code

Comment: This is my updated JSfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/3J2Ns/59/

Comment: What does this has to do with jQuery UI?

Comment: Really i do not know how to match table row values and selected dropdown box value..i want to display only matching row

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone for a server side solution, where you got a search result returned and the table replaced with the results.

If you for some reason want to do this manually on the frontend, one out of the box solution would be to assign each row classes that equates to the select values applicable for that row.

Also store all these class names as an array.

Write a function that hides all the classes, and another that shows all the classes. eg: for each class display none;

Then write a function that would on search, if both of the selects are empty, show all.

Else hide all and then show for each selected classes.

Your table html should be like this (add the 'result-row' class for all rows):

```
<table ...>
    ...
   <tr class="Apple Active result-row">
      <td> Apple </td> 
      <td>Active</td>
   </tr>
    ... //repeat the same for every row
</table>
```

You have used input checkboxes, but havent given them a name. You need to give them a name for each group.
eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Draft" name="option"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Active" name="option"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Motorola" name="option"/>
```

They can all be given the same name since for your purpose, it would both be used for filtering the same list. If there was a requirement to separate them out, I would give each group its own name.

In the javascript:

```
function hideAll() {
  $('.result-row').hide();
}

function showAll() {
  $('.result-row').show();
}

function showFiltered() {
   if ($('input[name="option"]:checked').length == 0) {
     showAll();
   }
   else {
     hideAll();
     $('input[name="option"]:checked').each(function() {
         $('.' + this.value).show();
     });
   }
}
```

Call function showFiltered() on click of any checkbox.
eg:

```
$('input[name="option"]').on('click', function () {
   showFiltered();
});
```

I have partially updated your jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/3J2Ns/60/
If you click on your select brand dropdown and select Apple, you would find Blackberry and HTC rows disappearing.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have limitted time and that is going to take up too much of it. But I will add some pseudo code to my answer, and can clarify if you have any questions.

Comment: simple  Arathi..how we can match table row values on selected dropdow box value?

Comment: Check my code, all the pieces are there. I havent tested it, but thats the general idea. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: it is not working..Arathi..if u do not mind can u edit my jsfiddle.

Comment: I am sorry, thats as far as I would be able to help you. You will have to try and work it out. This is a hint towards the logic. The fun part in programming is figuring out how to do it. I hope you have fun figuring it out! My work day is starting, so cannot spend any more time, sorry!

Comment: Ok, out of curiosity I partially updated your jsfilddle by copy pasting my solution. It seems to work. I had named the class wrong in my function previously, but that could easily be verified. I believe this would work.The fiddle is in my answer. Please see my answer above.